# Deviance Table for zeroinfl Objects

Tags: r, glm, anova

I would like to assess the deviance reduction of single coefficients for the negative-binomial part of my zero inflated model.

Is there an option to achieve a result similar to anova(glm) with a zeroinfl object in R?

Many thanks.

Comment: not easily, that I can see:  `drop1()` doesn't work. `step()` does work, though ...

Comment: You can fit the model with the variable of interest omitted and then conduct a likelihood ratio test with `lrtest()`. The reason that `drop1()` does not work easily is that the regressor variable can be omitted either from the count part of the model or the zero-inflation part of the model or both. Hence, the recommended way is to fit the two models of interest in advance.